# How to automatically change the font color of a TcustomEdit when we set readonly to true

Tags: delphi

I want to update the font color of all my edit when they are set to readonly. For this I update TCustomEdit like this:

```
TMyCustomEdit = class(TCustomEdit)
private
  procedure EMSetReadOnly        (var Message: TMessage);      message 
end; 

procedure TMyCustomEdit.EMSetReadOnly (var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  font.Color := clred;
end;
```

But i do not understand why this not work :(
Ideally i want that my **readonly** **Edit** to have the same design than a **disabled** **Tedit**

Comment: Maybe you need to Refresh your edit. If you want your readonly text edit to look like disabled text edit, why not just disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for starters, your code is incomplete, it should look more like this instead:

```
type
  TMyCustomEdit = class(TCustomEdit)
  private
    procedure EMSetReadOnly(var Message: TMessage); message EM_SETREADONLY;
    procedure UpdateFont;
  protected
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
  end;

procedure TMyCustomEdit.EMSetReadOnly(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  UpdateFont;
end;

procedure TMyCustomEdit.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  UpdateFont;
end;

procedure TMyCustomEdit.UpdateFont;
begin
  if (GetWindowLongPtr(Handle, GWL_STYLE) and ES_READONLY) <> 0 then
    Font.Color := clRed
  else
    Font.Color := clWindowText;
end;
```

With that said, to work correctly at runtime, you need to make sure that all of your Edit objects are actually using this class and not the standard `TEdit` class.  If you want to do this at design-time, you would have to put this class into a package and install it into the IDE.

A simpler way is to just turn this into an interposer class instead:

```
type
  TEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtls.TEdit)
    ... same code as above ...
  end;
```

Place this class declaration *above* your TForm class declaration. Or in a separate unit that is included in your `uses` clause *after* the `Vcl.StdCtrls` unit. Either way, the DFM streaming system will use the *last* declared definition of `TEdit` for all `TEdit` objects in the `TForm`. No IDE installation required.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I was going to, but I decided to make sure the change is actually applied to the `HWND` before changing the Font. Then I thought, if the `ReadOnly` property setter doesn't use `EM_SETREADONLY`, if it recreates the `HWND` instead (the VCL likes to do that a lot), I would account for that, too. There is a third possibility, if the property uses `SetWindowLong/Ptr(GWL_STYLE)` to set `ES_READONLY` directly, there is no notification for that, so I haven't accounted for that yet. I don't have access to Delphi at the moment to see how `ReadOnly` is actually implemented.

Comment: It sends the message, in case the handle is allocated... otherwise only sets FReadOnly. The getter reads FReadOnly.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Then all the more reason for the class to handle both the message and the `CreateWnd()` method.